# If $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $X$ is limit point compact, then $f(X)$ is limit point compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> If $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $X$ is limit point compact, then $f(X)$ is limit point compact.

Apparently, people seem to [disagree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177796/compact-for-limit-point-and-continous-function) [on](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269464/if-f-is-a-continuous-map-from-x-to-y-with-x-limit-point-compact-does-it-follow) whether the result is true or not, with those claiming that it's false giving counterexamples that no one protests. The definition of limit point compactness I'm using is that every infinite subset contains a limit point. Under this definition, I believe the result is true.

Proof: Suppose $B = \{f(x) : x \in A\}$ is an infinite subset of $f(X).$ For every $b \in B,$ pick $b^* \in f^{-1}(\{b\}) \cap A$ and define $A' = \{ b^* : b \in B\}.$ Then $A'$ is an infinite subset of $X$ and $f$ restricted to $A'$ is injective. Since $A'$ is an infinite subset of $X,$ it has a limit point $a.$ Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $f(a).$ Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of $a,$ so it contains a point $b \in A'$ such that $b \ne a,$ whereupon $U$ contains $f(b) \in B.$ By the injectivity of $f$ on $A',$ we have $f(b) \ne f(a).$ Since $U$ was arbitrary, $f(a)$ is a limit point of $A'$ and $f(X)$ is limit point compact.

So is the result true or not? If not, what's the subtle flaw in my proof? It's time to settle the debate once and for all.

Comment: If you look a the answer claiming that the result is true, there is a comment explaining why this fails. Why don't you try to understand the negative answer?

Comment: @Javi The counterexample and my proof can't be valid at the same time. I'm trying to see where either goes wrong.

Comment: After your edit you're now assuming injectivity in your argument, the answer with the counterexample says that when $f$ is injective the result is true, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: @Javi An infinite subset can't have repeated elements. That would be an infinite multiset.

Comment: If you define $\{f(x):x\in A\}$ and $f(x)=f(y)$, the element $f(x)$ appears once in the set, but it can appear twice in a sequence.

Comment: @Javi How is that a problem? If $f$ is constant on $A,$ then $\{f(x) : x \in A\}$ is not an infinite set.

Comment: I map can be not injective but have an infinite image, it doesn't need to be constant.

Comment: @Javi What's wrong with my new proof? There should no longer be any injectivity concerns.

Comment: If your definition of limit point compactness is that every infinite subset *contains* a limit point, then not even compact Hausdorff spaces need to be limit point compact. The common definition is that $X$ is limit point compact if every infinite subset $S$ of $X$ has a limit point in $X$, not necessarily in $S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite clear cut IMO. If limit point compact means "every infinite set has an  limit point (in $X$)", the result is false for general spaces.

Simple example: $X=\Bbb N \times \{0,1\}$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the trivial/indiscrete topology and $\Bbb N$ has its usual discrete topology. $X$ has the product topology of these.
$Y=\Bbb N$ (same) and $f(x,i)=x$ is the first projection.

$f$ is continuous of course (all projections are on a product) and also open (likewise) and closed (as $\{0,1\}$ is compact). A very nice function.

$X$ is limit point compact, because if $A \subseteq X$ is any non-empty set and $(n,0) \in A$ then $(n,1)$ is a limit point of $A$, and also if $(n,1) \in A$, $(n,0)$ is a limit point of $A$.

But $f[X]=Y$ is discrete and so is not limit point compact (no set has a limit point at all).

As to your "proof", and for an infinite $B \subseteq Y$, there indeed is an infinite $A \subseteq X$ such that $f[A]=B$.
E.g. in the example if we take $A=\Bbb N \times \{0\}$ which satisfies that $f[A]  = Y$ and $f| A$ is injective, we have that a limit point of $A$, say $(0,1)$ is mapped into $f[A]$ (namely to $0$) and is not a limit point of $f[A]$, so $f$ is *no longer* injective on $A \cup \{(0,1)\}$ and we lose the limit point property. Note that the limit point $p$ of $A$ is **not** garantueed to be a member of $A$ (it only needs to be a limit point of $A$ in $X$!) and $f$ is no longer injective on $A \cup \{p\}$. $f^{-1}[U]$ (in your notation) does contain a point of $A$ different from $p$ but that point an $p$ still have the same $f$-value! So $U$ does not contain a point different from $f(p)$ and $f(p)$ is not a limit point of $f[A]$..

If $X$ is assumed to be $T_1$ all "troubles" go away, and limit point compactness becomes equivalent with countable compactness, whcih is (quite easily) preserved by continuity. Hence the bad separation properties of the example, they are necessary.

Answer (score 2):

As you observe, some people offer proofs; others offer counterexamples without any response. But the *proofs* all *do* have responses, showing a missing point, and that same point is missing from your proof, namely, that the values $f(a_i)$ must be distinct. So the current state is

Proofs: several, with problems.

Counterexample: one, unchallenged

New proof: still has problem.

I'm betting on the counterexample.

As for where your proof goes wrong? It's at this sentence "WLOG, we may assume $f()\ne ()$ if $, \in $ are distinct."

NB: The answer above was to a version of the question that read rather differently from the current one. It was this:

> Proof: Suppose $B = \{f(x) : x \in A\}$ is an infinite subset of
> $f(X).$ WLOG, we may assume $f(x) \ne f(y)$ if $x, y \in A$ are
> distinct. Since $A$ is an infinite subset of $X,$ it has a limit point
> $a.$ Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $f(a).$ Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is a
> neighborhood of $a,$ so it contains a point $b \ne a \in A,$ whereupon
> $U$ contains $f(b) \in B.$ Since $U$ was arbitrary, $f(a)$ is a limit
> point of $A$ and $f(X)$ is limit point compact.

Comment: They are distinct because $B$ is a set, and elements in a set are distinct as opposed to elements in a multiset.

Comment: My proof of this assumption: by the axiom of choice, we may pick $A' \subseteq A$ such that $f(A') = B$ and $f: A' \to B$ is injective. Now redefine $B = \{f(x) : x \in A'\}.$

Comment: I can agree that you can newly define A'. Still, in the middle of your proof, I don't see a particular reason that f(b) differs from f(a). For f(a) to become a limit point of B, its arbitrary neighborhood should contain an element of B 'different from' f(a).

Comment: Since $f$ is injective on $A'$ and $a, b \in A'$ are distinct, we have $f(a) \ne f(b).$

Comment: $a$ need not reside in $A'$, isn't it?

Comment: The new $a$ does because I am using the fact that $A'$ is infinite and picking a limit point $a \in A'.$

Comment: That is stronger than the usual limit point compactness. If $X$ is limit point compact, every infinite subset $A$ should have a limit point inside $X$, not necessarily inside $A$.

Comment: I checked my book again and it says "every infinite subset has a limit point." However, the book did not say "has a limit point in $X$", so I interpreted this as the subset containing a limit point. I believe we have finally found the source of the disagreement. The author needs to add a clarification if it is indeed the case that the limit point can be anywhere in the whole space.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the case. Otherwise, for example, $[0, 1]$ will not be considered limit point compactness if you consider $A = \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. If you believe in the statement that compact spaces should be limit point compact, you should alter your convention.

Comment: @Displayname It is "has a limit point in $X$", not in $A$. If we demand that even a compact space like $[0,1]$ would not be "limit point compact" for that notion.

Comment: Compactness implying limit point compactness is a theorem in my book and I agree it should hold. I even read and understood the theorem earlier, but did not realize it was using a weaker definition. I've gone back and spotted the exact step (subset has no limit points $\Rightarrow$ it is closed) where the definition has to be weaker. Now I should be clear of any misconceptions about definitions.